# Managing Korean multi-byte string with mb_substr() produces gibberish

Tags: php, mysql, string, character-encoding, cjk

I have a `string` in Korean(`multi byte string`), with `UTF-8` encoding, when using `mb_substr()` it fails to detect it as `multi byte` and hence `mb_substr()` works like `substr()` and I end up getting gibberish characters like "�" at the end of the `string`.

> 星期三大象键盘开裂青蛙混杂纪念碑问题面包车斑马线 수요일 코끼리 키보드 개구리 뒤범벅 비석 이 질문에 반 얼룩말을 크래킹

Also using `mb_detect_encoding()` I get `UTF-8`, any ideas where am I going wrong?

The current function that I am using is :

```
function cleanseData($data, $mode = false, $limit = 0) {
    if ($mode) {
        $data = (mb_strlen ( $data ) > ($limit + 3)) ? mb_substr ( $data, 0, $limit, mb_detect_encoding($data) ) . '...' : $data;
    }
    $data = utf8tohtml ( $data, true );
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Could You please, show some code?

Comment: @Kamiccolo done that

Comment: What PHP version is this?

Comment: @Evert PHP Version 5.5.16

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any of the mb or utf8tohtml functions.  State the everything at every stage is utf8.  See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#)

� probably comes from not having utf8 characters in the first place, and using the default `SET NAMES latin1` instead of `SET NAMES utf8`.

Could it be that your text is EUCKR?  Please provide the hex for some character; I may be able to dig further.

Also please do this to see what is in the table:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

That will give a clue as to whether the data was mangled going *into* the table, or mangled coming *out*.

Correctly encoded in utf8 (or utf8mb4), `星期三` is hex `E6989F E69C9F E4B889`, and `보드 개` is hex `EBB3B4 EB939C 20 EAB09C` (I added spaces for clarity.)

What you have is a combination of Chinese and Korean, correct?  I strongly recommend utf8mb4 throughout.